# How do I package source and documentation jars separately on deploy?

Tags: maven

I notice that most distributions package their artifacts like

```
my-1.0.jar
my-1.0-sources.jar
my-1.0-documentation.jar
```

when I do a deploy I currently only get the `my-1.0.jar` how do I get the sources and documentation generated as separate jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `maven-source-plugin` and `maven-javadoc-plugin` to the build.plugins section of my parent `pom.xml`. Worth saying that I originally accidentally put them in `pluginManagement` and of course that would only work if I manually included them in the child.

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-sources</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
```